# unable open android device monitor in android studio,

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

after i upgraded my android studio,the android device monitor could't be open, here is the event log:

```
11:30:52 PM adb I   902 42507 usb_osx.cpp:259] Found vid=18d1 pid=4ee2 serial=00fa8d620ebcb959
11:30:52 PM adb I   902 42507 usb_osx.cpp:259]
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem? how to solve it

Comment: You've tried the usual *turn it off and on again* trick then? (`adb kill-server`, `adb devices`)

Comment: That is an INFO log and it says it found a device... So what exactly are you trying to show by that event?